# Froala does not upload HTTPS images of type blob:https

Tags: javascript, blob, froala

I was using Froala 3.2.1 and when I copied images from sites whose `src` property starts with "`blob:https://example.com/image-id`" it pastes the image correctly, and starts uploading the content to my server.

However, in the latest versions (4.0.12), when I copy this type of image (right click > copy image) and paste it into Froala, it simply adds the broken image, without trying to upload. Another thing I noticed is that now Chrome displays an error message, which if I go back to 3.2.1 it doesn't occur.

Below is the HTML generated by Froala when pasting the image:

```
<img data-fr-image-pasted="true" src="blob:https://example.com/id-id-id-id-id" style="width: 300px; display: block; float: none; vertical-align: top; margin: 5px auto; text-align: center;">
```

Even the code they suggest to convert a pasted image to base64 is not triggered by this type of content.

This is the error that is displayed by Chrome:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: blob:https://example.com/id-id-id-id-id
```

I use the code below to generate the editor.

```
var editor = new FroalaEditor('div#froala-editor', {
    imageUploadURL: 'https:/example.com/uploadImage', /*Use to test upload image to server*/
    imageUploadRemoteUrls: true, /*Use to test upload image to server*/
    events: {
        "image.beforeUpload": function (files) {
            var editor = this;
            if (files.length) {
                // Create a File Reader.
                var reader = new FileReader();
                // Set the reader to insert images when they are loaded.
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var result = e.target.result;
                    editor.image.insert(result, null, null, editor.image.get());
                };
                // Read image as base64.
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
            }
            editor.popups.hideAll();
            // Stop default upload chain.
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

What can be done to fix this behavior?